# Cannot set correct timezone in Docker container on Windows 10

Tags: docker, timezone

No matter how hard I tried, I cannot set the timezone correctly in Windows 10.
My local time and timezone are correct! I doubled check everything.
The timezone doesn't set automatically. And everything looks fine on the surface.

The problem is while running a docker image, I'm getting a completely different date.
First, I wanted to find the root cause of it. And I set the hardware clock to UTC. It was working fine, until today.
Again I have a completely date. While running the docker image, I just checked the logs and the docker container time is a day in advance.

I'm about to lose my mind.
I event use `docker -e TZ=Europe/..` to set it manually. But still no solutions.

Comment: Can you post a Dockerfile that lets us reproduce your problem?

Comment: surprisingly I'm running Postgres official docker image on my local. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0):

you can set set System timezone in Dockerfile itself by adding this...
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata

Comment: as I said even passing it as env variable doesn't work. The date still shows 22nd of June.